# Phase Views in manifest after RVT model translation, how to detect or suppress?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a `Revit model` where we have configured a single `3D View` in Publish Settings.  We published that model to `BIM 360` and are using `Forge` to extract the list of `3D Views`.

We notice that after the model is translated, the only views available in `BIM360` are the views included as set in the Publish Settings in `Revit`, irregardless of phase, but are under the Phases icon, when we extract the Views from the manifest we also get additional views that were created because some objects belong to different Phases. We don’t seem to be able to distinguish between the different views or see a relationship between different phases of the same view.

Is there a way to do that? or not to translate the additional phase views at all?

The extract below shows us the {3D} view and the Phase Views created “Existing” and “New Construction” using GET 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest

**Manifest:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those phased 3D views are from the mater view for each phase, you can suppress them by submitting translation jobs like below:

```
// POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
// with `x-ads-force: true` Reuest header

{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YWRuZGVtby9ob3VzZS5ydnQ"
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "2d",
          "3d"
        ],
        "advanced": {
          "generateMasterViews": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note.** The `generateMasterViews` option in BIM360 Docs is `turned on` by default and the translation job will be submitted automatically while the model was uploaded to Docs managed bucket successfully, currently.

**Note 2.** Triggering any **translation** jobs **yourself** on the **models** of the **BIM360 Docs** **will consume extra Forge Cloud Credits.** So, you have to use it carefully at your own risk.

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure

Comment: A recent change (July/August) in the way the RVT is automatically translated on a successful upload to BIM360 Docs means we cannot submit the job ourselves like we used to do as it caused corruption in the data due to simultaneous translations (logged). 1. Can we disable the automatic translation? 2. Failing that how do we detect these views are phase views?

Comment: Unfortunately, this translation job is submitted by our internal service automatically that you cannot disable it as I know. For a phase view, Both values of its `name` and `phaseNames` are the same. You could use this to tell them apart from the manifest in your code.